# blank record/row is added instead of the row with entered details in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have written a simple code in ReactJS in which records are shown in table. Name in each row is visible however designation and salary of a record/row becomes visible on clicking that row. The problem is that when I ADD a new record by entering the details (name, designation, & salary), a blank record is added instead of the record with entered details. Please tell what can be the issue?

**Code:**

```
var RecordsComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            records: [{name:'Kevin Petersen',designation:"Junior Software Engineer",salary:"$1000"}, {name:'Michel Johnson',designation:"Senior Software Engineer",salary:"$2500"},{name:'Shane Bond',designation:"HR Manager",salary:"$1250"}],
            newRecord: [{name:'new name', designation:'new designation', salary:'new salary'}],
            expandedRecords : []
        }
    },
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div className="container" style={{"width" : "50%", "alignment" : "center"}}>
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colSpan={2}>Records</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {this.state.records.map((r) => (
                        <tr>
                            <td onClick={this.showDetails}>
                                {r.name}
                                {this.renderDesignation(r.name)}<span></span>
                                {this.renderSalary(r.name)}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button className="tableBtn" onClick={() => this.deleteRow(r)}>Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input type="text" id={"newNameId"} placeholder={"name"} onChange={this.updateNewName}></input>
                <input type="text" id={"newDesId"} placeholder={"designation"} onChange={this.updateNewDesignation}></input>
                <input type="text" id={"newSalId"} placeholder={"salary"} onChange={this.updateNewSalary}></input>
                <button id="addBtn" onClick={this.addRow}>ADD</button>
            </div>
        );
    },
    updateNewName: function(component) {
        this.setState({
            newRecord: {name:component.target.value},
        });
    },
    updateNewDesignation: function(component) {
        this.setState({
            newRecord: {designation:component.target.value},
        });
    },
    updateNewSalary: function(component) {
        this.setState({
            newRecord: {salary:component.target.value}
        });
    },
    addRow : function() {
        var records = this.state.records;
        var newRecord = this.state.newRecord;
        records.push(newRecord)
        this.setState({records: records})
    },
    deleteRow : function(record) {
        this.setState({
            records: this.state.records.filter(r => r !== record)
        });
    },
    showDetails : function(record) {
        let expandedRecords = this.state.expandedRecords;
        expandedRecords.push(record.target.innerHTML);
        this.setState({...this.state, expandedRecords: expandedRecords });
    },
    renderDesignation : function(name){
        if(this.state.expandedRecords.includes(name)) {
            var row = this.state.records.filter(r=> r.name === name)[0]
            return(<td>{"Designation: "+row.designation}</td>);
        }
        return;
    },
    renderSalary : function(name){
        if(this.state.expandedRecords.includes(name)) {
            var row = this.state.records.filter(r=> r.name === name)[0]
            return(<td>Salary: {row.salary}</td>);
        }
        return;
    }
});
React.render(
    <RecordsComponent />,
    document.getElementById('display')
);
```

Comment: Try not to mutate your `state`. On `addRow` for example, use `this.setState({ records: [...this.state.records, newRecord] })`. Also, You are mapping through the array and not assigning any `key` to `tr` elements.

Comment: Note that `createClass` is deprecated and in the next version of React it won't be supported at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are using setState rite? if you use something like this,

```
this.setState({
            newRecord: {salary:component.target.value}
        });
```

The existing state's newRecord attribute will entirely get replaced. It will not update the attribute newRecord of the state. So at this point, the state will be like this

```
this.state = {//otherproperties,
              newRecord: {salary:'some value'}
```

It will not be like this

```
this.state = {//other properties,
              newRecord: {name: 'some name', salary: 'some salary', designation : 'some designation'}
```

So, instead of doing like this, we should mutate the state whenever you are updating the state.

Also, I noticed you were using innerHTML of the entire  tag so it contains not only the name but the salary, designation also. So on clicking the name, its not rendering the designation and salary. So the complete component should look something like this.

```
var RecordsComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            records: [{name:'Kevin Petersen',designation:"Junior Software Engineer",salary:"$1000"}, {name:'Michel Johnson',designation:"Senior Software Engineer",salary:"$2500"},{name:'Shane Bond',designation:"HR Manager",salary:"$1250"}],
            newRecord: [{name:'new name', designation:'new designation', salary:'new salary'}],
            expandedRecords : []
        }
    },
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div className="container" style={{"width" : "50%", "alignment" : "center"}}>
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colSpan={2}>Records</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {this.state.records.map((r) => (
                        <tr>
                            <td onClick={this.showDetails}>
                                {r.name}
                            </td>
                            {this.renderDesignation(r.name)}
                            {this.renderSalary(r.name)}
                            <td>
                                <button className="tableBtn" onClick={() => this.deleteRow(r)}>Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input type="text" id={"newNameId"} placeholder={"name"} onChange={this.updateNewName}></input>
                <input type="text" id={"newDesId"} placeholder={"designation"} onChange={this.updateNewDesignation}></input>
                <input type="text" id={"newSalId"} placeholder={"salary"} onChange={this.updateNewSalary}></input>
                <button id="addBtn" onClick={this.addRow}>ADD</button>
            </div>
        );
    },
    updateNewName: function(component) {
        this.setState({...this.state,
            newRecord: {...this.state.newRecord,name:component.target.value},
        });
    },
    updateNewDesignation: function(component) {
        this.setState({...this.state,
            newRecord: {...this.state.newRecord,designation:component.target.value},
        });
    },
    updateNewSalary: function(component) {
        this.setState({...this.state,
            newRecord: {...this.state.newRecord,salary:component.target.value}
        });
    },
    addRow : function() {
        var records = this.state.records;
        var newRecord = this.state.newRecord;
        records.push(newRecord)
        this.setState({records: records})
    },
    deleteRow : function(record) {
        this.setState({
            records: this.state.records.filter(r => r !== record)
        });
    },
    showDetails : function(record) {
        let expandedRecords = this.state.expandedRecords;
        expandedRecords.push(record.target.innerHTML);
        this.setState({...this.state, expandedRecords: expandedRecords });
    },
    renderDesignation : function(name){
        if(this.state.expandedRecords.includes(name)) {
            var row = this.state.records.filter(r=> r.name === name)[0]
            return(<td>{"Designation: "+row.designation}</td>);
        }
        return;
    },
    renderSalary : function(name){
        if(this.state.expandedRecords.includes(name)) {
            var row = this.state.records.filter(r=> r.name === name)[0]
            return(<td>Salary: {row.salary}</td>);
        }
        return;
    }
});
```